# Limit of p-Norm without absolute value

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

It is well known, that $\| x\|_p\longrightarrow \| x\|_\infty$ as $p\to\infty$ for $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$. Under which assumptions does the more general statement hold, that
\begin{equation}
\left|\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^p\right|^{1/p}\xrightarrow[p\to\infty]{}\| x\|_\infty
\end{equation}
where $x=(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)\in(\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0])^n$?

Starting with
\begin{equation}
\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \left|\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^p\right|^{1/p} \!\!\!\!\! = \| x \|_\infty \cdot \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \left|\sum_{j=1}^n \left( \frac{x_j}{\| x \|_\infty} \right)^p \right|^{1/p} \!\!\!\!\! = \| x \|_\infty \cdot \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} |S_p|^{1/p}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
S_p=\sum_{j=1}^n \left( \frac{x_j}{\| x \|_\infty} \right)^p,
\end{equation}
we got $|S_p|\leq n$, thus it'd be enough to show that $S_p$ is bounded away from $0$ uniformely in $p$. Maybe writing
\begin{equation}
S_p=\sum_{j=1}^n r_j^pe^{ip\varphi_j}
\end{equation}
where $0\leq r_j\leq1$ for all $j$ and $r_j=1$ for at least one $j$, could be useful, but I have no idea how to go on.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If $p\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ the power $x^p$ is not defined for $x < 0$.

Comment: It is well defined on $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: Then it would be good to put that assumption in the hypotheses

Comment: For $|\alpha| < \pi$, we have $$ \left| 1^p + (e^{i\alpha})^p \right|^{1/p} = \left| 1 + e^{i p\alpha} \right|^{1/p} = \left( 2 \left| \cos (p\alpha/2) \right| \right)^{1/p}. $$ As $p\to\infty$ along positive reals, this oscillates between $0$ and $1$. On the other hand, if there is a unique $k$ for which $|x_k| = \|x\|_{\infty}$ then the statement is still true since $|S_p| \to 1$ as $p\to\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand that. How does it prove the statement?

Comment: My comment is not a complete answer, but the point is that the behavior of $|S_p|$ depends on whether $\# \{ k : |x_k| = \|x\|_{\infty} \}$ is equal to $1$ or grater than $1$. In the former case, it is clear from the formula that $|S_p| \to 1$ as $p\to\infty$. In the latter case, my comment shows that even when $n = 2$ the situation is quite wild; $|S_p|$ converges exactly when $x_1$ and $x_2$ have the same phase. (In my previous comment, I need an extra assumption that $\alpha \neq 0$. Sorry for this.) When $n \geq 3$ the situation is much harder to analyze but I expect a similar criterion.

Comment: Ok, of course, I got it.